Universal quantifier over disjunction in intuitionistic logic
I have  a question about the following sequent, valid in classical logic:
$$\forall x [\phi(x) \vee \psi] \vdash \forall x [\phi(x)] \vee \psi$$
Importantly, we assume $\psi$ does not contain any free $x$. Is this sequent valid also in intuitionistic logic?
The converse sequent is not hard to prove, but with this direction I am stuck. The inference rules are not immediately helpful since both the disjunction and the quantifier are on their respective "wrong sides" of the sequent.
For analogous sequents involving conjunctions, we have logical equivalences for both quantifiers, for the existential quantifier we have logical equivalence also for disjunction.
For a finite universe of discourse, this reduces to the distributive law. For example, in  a two-element universe we have.
$$[\phi(a) \vee \psi]\wedge[\phi(b) \vee \psi] \equiv [\phi(a)\wedge \phi(b)] \vee \psi$$
which holds in any Heyting algebra, but what about infinite universes?
In classical logic, with the law of excluded middle, $\top \vdash \psi \vee \neg \psi$, the proof is straightforward:
$$\tag{1}\label{one}
\psi \wedge \forall x [\phi(x) \vee \psi] \vdash \psi \vdash \forall x [\phi(x)] \vee\psi$$
and
$$\neg \psi \wedge \forall x [\phi(x) \vee \psi] \vdash 
\neg \psi \wedge (\phi(x) \vee \psi) \equiv [\neg \psi \wedge \phi(x)]\vee[\neg \psi \wedge \psi]
\equiv \neg \psi \wedge \phi(x)\vdash \phi(x)$$
We used the fact that $\forall x [\chi(x)] \vdash \chi(x)$, and monotony of the conjunction. Since the lhs does not contain free $x$, universal quantifier introduction on the rhs gives
$$
\tag{2}\label{two}
\neg \psi \vee \forall x [\phi(x) \vee \psi] \vdash \forall x [\phi(x)] \vdash
\forall x [\phi(x)] \vee \psi$$
Since the right hand sides of \eqref{one} and \eqref{two} are identical, we can combine the two using the disjunction introduction, and then apply the distributive law:
$$(\neg \psi \vee \psi) \wedge \forall x [\phi(x) \vee \psi] \vdash
\forall x [\phi(x)] \vee \psi$$
The sequent then follows from the excluded middle.
Is there an intuitionistic proof, or a simple counterargument? A counterexample would have to be probably an object in a non-classical topos such that the inclusion corresponding to the sequent does not hold.
Edit 2024-10-19
Thanks to Daniel Schepler, I have learned how Kripke frames work, and it turns out Kripke himself, in one of his original papers, (scan avaliable here),
on page 101, deals with the exact sequent I was asking about!
Kripke's counterexample is even simpler, just two frames $G$ and $H$, with $G \leq H$, with a one-element set $\lbrace a \rbrace$ at $G$ and a two-element set $\lbrace a,b \rbrace$ at $H$. Now $\psi$ is false at $G$ but true at $H$, while
$\phi(a)$ is true (both at $G$ and $H$) and $\phi(b)$ is false (where it makes sense, at $H$).
So, in this model, both $\psi$ and $\forall x [\phi(x)]$ are false (The quantifier argument does not hold for all points of $H$). However, $\forall x [\phi(x) \vee \psi]$ is true, because $\phi$ is true everywhere at $G$ (i.e., at its only point $a$), while $\psi$ is true at $H$, so the disjunction is true for both $a$ and $b$.
Another insightful bit is that we cannot assert that $\forall x [(x = e_1) \vee (x = e_2)]$ in this model. This is because we need to fix the valuation of the free $e_1$ and $e_2$ to some shared elements of $G$ and $H$ (the valuation must be "constant" across frames), but $G$ only contains one element, $a$, so we have to value both $e_1$ and $e_2$ as $a$. As a result $(x = e_1) \vee (x = e_2)$ will not hold for all elements of $H$. So the fact that the frame "looks" finite is in no conflict with the distributive law I mentioned above. Since it is not really finite in the sense of satisfying $\forall x [(x = e_1) \vee (x = e_2)]$, the universal quantifier does not reduce to a simple conjunction.

Here is a counterexample using a Kripke frame: $K$ will be a branching poset $\{ 0, 1, 2 \}$ with $0 \le 1$ and $0\le 2$.  $X$ will be the presheaf which is $\emptyset$ at 0, $\{ x \}$ at 1, and $\{ y \}$ at 2.  The truth assignments will be:

At 0, $\psi$ is false.
At 1, $\psi$ is false and $\phi(x)$ is true.
At 2, $\psi$ is true and $\phi(y)$ is false.

It is straightforward to check that in this model, $0 \Vdash \forall x [\phi(x) \lor \psi]$, but $0 \not\Vdash \forall x [\phi(x)] \lor \psi$.

And if you're using a logical formalism that requires $X$ to be inhabited, you could add $z$ to $X$ at each point, and let $\phi(z)$ be true at each point.  (But such a logical formalism, for example, would not be sound with respect to the internal logic of a topos, so I'd argue that it would have serious applicability issues.)

Thx, this is probably the best answer, and I am saying "probably" only because I have to confess I know very little about the Kripke-Joyal semantics. You gave a me a reason to learn a bit more about it.

It's not so much Kripke-Joyal semantics as just the definitions from a Kripke frame.  (Sure, you could view a Kripke frame as a simple way to construct a counterexample in a presheaf topos, and the definitions reduce to the same thing as the Kripke-Joyal semantics.  But in this case, in particular the interpretations of $\lor$ and $\exists$ are much simpler.)

Thanks again, I have amended my question with more explanation. You have pointed me in the right direction.

One way to show that your principle is not valid intuitionistically is to give a Brouwerian counterexample, i.e. show that it implies some well-known constructive taboo. In this case, we can show that it implies the limited principle of omniscience:
Let $\phi$ be a decidable predicate over the natural numbers, i.e. such that $\forall n. \phi(n) \lor \neg \phi(n)$. Setting $\psi = \exists n. \neg \phi(n)$, we deduce that $\forall n. (\phi(n) \lor \psi)$; hence, using your principle, $(\forall n. \phi(n)) \lor (\exists n. \neg \phi(n))$.

Thx,  I missed that completely.  So if the sequent from my question holds, we have LPO, meaning the resulting fragment of logic is "somewhere half way between intuitionistic and classical". Analogous to how de Morgan algebra is between Heyting and Boolean. It nicely explains why this sequent has something extra in it.

Intuitively (ahem) this is non-constructive: a proof of $\forall x . (\phi (x) \lor \psi)$ is a function that takes $x$ as input and returns a proof of either $\phi (x)$ or $\psi$, and to convert this into a proof of $(\forall x . \phi (x)) \lor \psi$ you would need to do a potentially unbounded search over $x$ to either confirm that $(\forall x . \phi (x))$ or obtain $\psi$. So, for example, if you had $\exists x . \lnot \phi (x)$ then it would follow.
But this is just handwaving.
Instead, consider the topological interpretation: imagine that we have some open subset $\phi \subseteq \Gamma \times X$ and an open subset $\psi \subseteq \Gamma$; then we are trying to compare the dual projection $\forall_X (\phi \cup (\psi \times X))$ and $\forall_X (\phi) \cup \psi$.
But the projection map $\Gamma \times X \to \Gamma$ is closed if and only if $\forall_X (\phi \cup (\psi \times X)) = \forall_X (\phi) \cup \psi$ for all $\phi$ and $\psi$, and $\Gamma \times X \to \Gamma$ is closed for all $\Gamma$ if and only if $X$ is compact.
Thus, we are led to an explicit counterexample.
Let $\Gamma$ be a topological space with a non-isolated closed point $q$, i.e. if  $F (q)$ is the set of all open neighbourhoods of $q$, then $\bigcap F (q)$ has empty interior.
Let $X = F (q)$ (with the discrete topology), let $\phi = \{ (p, \chi) \in \Gamma \times X : p \in \chi \}$, and let $\psi = \Gamma \setminus \{ p \}$.
Thus, the projection $\Gamma \times X \to \Gamma$ is a local homeomorphism (trivially), $\phi$ is an open subset of $\Gamma \times X$, and $\psi$ is an open subset of $\Gamma$.
Interpreted in the internal logic of $\textbf{Sh} (\Gamma)$, this is the desired counterexample.
Indeed, it is clear that $\phi \cup (\psi \times X) = \Gamma \times X$, so certainly $\forall_X (\phi \cup (\psi \times X)) = \Gamma$; but $\forall_X (\phi) = \emptyset$ by hypothesis, so $\forall_X (\phi) \cup \psi \subsetneqq \Gamma$.

Thanks so much.  Very simple, but your "design" of $\phi$ is very clever none the less.
